# In Excel for Mac how do I fill all blank cells with the same text? Cmd+Enter is not working

Tags: excel-2010

I used to use excel on Windows, and Go To > Blanks highlights all blank cells, then typing the text I want and using Ctrl+Enter filled all the selected blank cells.

I am trying to do the same thing on a Mac, and Ctrl+Enter or Cmd+Enter are not filling all the blank cells.  What is the correct key combination to fill all selected blank cells?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. S/O is a site that helps people who are programming by writing code. Sounds like you've got a problem that involves using the excel program instead. It's not that your question isn't important, but it isn't a good fit for the stated purpose of S/O... you'd get more help if you moved it to our sister site Superuser - which is all about using applications. You can get there by clicking the StackExchange link at the top left of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it.  It is Option+Enter.